# Edge browser does not sync bookmarks in real time

Tags: windows-10, sync, bookmarks, microsoft-edge, windows-10-v1511

I'm using the latest available version of Edge (25.10586.0.0) in Windows 10 on my devices like the main work pc, my Win10 tablet and a Microsoft Lumia 950 phone. When I bookmark a website or add it to the reading list in the Edge browseron my main pc, it does not appear in the corresponding list on the other devices in a reasonable amount of time. It may take several hours when I see the new bookmark there!

Is it the expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong? Sure, I have the `Sync your content` option in Edge and the OS turned on. Is there a way I can initialize this syncing manually if I need it urgently?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is the expecting behavior, and no... you are not doing anything wrong.

I've been doing some research on my own... For me the average time for synchronization is about 2-7 minutes. However, some of the outliers were up to 20 minutes.

Comment: Take a look at this article for more information about How Synchronization Works: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/how-edge-synchronization-works/ce5e3d26-9090-4490-a40d-c3252be268b0